# WebSocket in Javascript not connecting to servlet

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to use Javascript websockets to connect to a Java servlet, but the onError function is always being called, and is not providing much information. My javascript:

```
var webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/test');

webSocket.onerror = function(event) {
  onError(event);
};

webSocket.onclose = function(event) {
    onClose(event);
};

webSocket.onopen = function(event) {
  onOpen(event);
};

webSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
  onMessage(event);
};

function onClose(event) {
    var code = event.code;
    var reason = event.reason;
    var wasClean = event.wasClean;
    alert(code + "; " + reason + "; " + wasClean);
}

function onMessage(event) {
    //do stuff
}

function onOpen(event) {
  webSocket.send('opening socket');
}

function onError(event) {
  alert(event.message);
}
```

For my servlet, I have

```
@ServerEndpoint("/test")
public class TranscoderSNSServlet extends HttpServlet {

    ...
}
```

The only useful error codes I've been able to find are that event.code = 1006, event.wasClean = false. The browser I am using definitely supports websockets. I am trying to run this on ElasticBeanstalk. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Okay you try to run this "on ElasticBeanstalk", but is that ElasticBeanstalk listening on your localhost on port 8080, and is your local firewall allowing that traffic?

Comment: It's deployed to EBS through Amazon. I've tried tons of combinations of URIs, including the EBS URL itself (xxx.elasticbeanstalk.com). I enabled all traffic to the ec2 instance it is working with, but it didn't help

Comment: Well then you should be contacting Amazon support, not posting on SO.

Comment: This is clearly something that SO can help with as I've seen many people post asking for help with AWS.